# Jsx honor white space in optgroup's label

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and have been trying for a few hours now to have my React component rendered from JSX to respect white space for an `<optgroup>` element's label property. What is boils down to is wanting these labels to be indented a little via white space usage.

Here is a very basic example of the render function:

```
    render: function () {
    var theLabel = "               OptionGroup Label";
    return (
        <select>
            <optgroup label={theLabel}>
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        )
}
```

No matter how many spaces I prefix the label with, they do not appear in the resulting output. I've tried using `&nbsp;` characters as well, but those result in that actual text showing in the output. I suppose I could instead use something else other than white spaces such as prefixing with hyphens, dots, etc, but I really want white space.

Tried not using a variable, but rather hard-coding spaces directly in the label attribute like this and again the white spaces do not appear in the output:

```
    render: function () {
    return (
        <select>
            <optgroup label="               OptionGroup Label">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        )
}
```

How can I get white spaces to stick?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM to see if the attributes of the rendered elements have the values you expect? While JSX has some gotchas with regard to whitespace between tags, as far as I know React doesn't modify the values of props in any way.

Comment: Looks like the unicode solution mentioned in the answer below is the way to go. When looking at the DOM, all the spaces in the label appear to be there, but they are getting ignored in the page. Looking at the DOM with the unicode approach, the unicode characters have been replaced with `&nbsp;` characters making the spaces take effect in the rendered page. Thanks @Jordan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the unicode representation - `'\u00A0'` - to get a non-breaking space into a string:

```
var theLabel = "\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0OptionGroup Label";
```

If your source file's character encoding is set appropriately, you should be able to run the above string through a browser's developer console and paste the result back into your code (then forget and wonder why it works sometime later).

Comment: Ahhh unicode! Thanks @Jonny . That did the trick. If I do that directly in the `<optgroup>` label tag, it doesn't work, but if I assign it to a variable and reference the variable in the label tag, it does work.